# Getting only numbers with `-` and `.` from the string using regexp in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace with empty (`''`) on unwanted string using `regexp` does not work as expected.

If I try to replace the start group it works `(^\w*)`. But I could not able to select the post fix of the number.`(\D*$)`.  How to combine both or what this the correct syntax to replace?

Example:

```
--123 should be -123
a-123 should be -123
!-123- should be -123
+-123.44x should be -123.44
--123.33- should be -123.33
```

When I try this get no output as expected `.replace(/[^-\d\.]\D*$/g, ""))`

Comment: What should be output for `-x123` ?

Comment: @3gwebtrain - per the many edits on your questions, there is no need to add "anyone help me", "please help me" etc. Readers know you need help; this is just noise. Please stick to technical writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My question would be: Why use [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to remove what you don't want, instead of [`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)ing what you do want?

```js
function getNumber(string) {
  const [match] = string.match(/-?\d+(\.\d+)?/) || [null];
  return match;
}

["--123", "a-123", "!-123", "!-123-", "+-123.44x", "--123.33-", "non-number"]
  .map(getNumber)
  .forEach(result => console.log(JSON.stringify(result)));
```

In the above snippet we use the regex `/-?\d+(\.\d+)?/`, which matches an optional `-`, followed by one or more decimals. These can be followed by a `.` but only if followed by one or more other decimals.

If there is no match then `null` is returned from `match()`. To prevent an exception when destructuring `const [match] = ...` we assign `[null]` instead.

Comment: Yes, agree. But I am looking for a solution on "onKeyUp" event with input element. where the user types with unwanted values.

Answer (score 2):

You may use following regex for search:

```bash
^\D*(?:(?=-)|\D)|(?<=\d)(?!\.\d)[^\d\n].*$
```

and replace it with just an empty string.

[Code Demo](https://regex101.com/r/99Vn3s/3)

**Code:**

```js
const rx = /^\D*(?:(?=-)|\D)|(?<=\d)(?!\.\d)[^\d\n].*$/g;

['--123',
'a-123',
'-x123',
'ab123',
'!-123',
'+-123.44x',
'---a-x123.x45-abc',
'--123.33-'].forEach(
   el => console.log(el, ' => ', el.replace(rx, ''))
);
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `\D*`: Match 0 or more non-digits
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `(?=-)`: We have a `-` at next position
  - `|`: OR
  - `\D`: Match any character that is not a digit
- `)`: End non-capture group
- `|`: OR
- `(?<=\d)`: Assert that we have a digit before the current position
- `(?!\.\d)`: Assert that we don't have dot and digit ahead
- `[^\d\n]`: Match a char that is not a digit and not a line break
- `.*`: Match anything
- `$`: End

Comment: @anubhva, you are doing excellent job.  as well when i type `---a-x123.x45-abc` it is giving the result as `123.x45`.  But need to get result as `123`

Comment: I have updated my answer, demo and description.

Answer (score 0):

Write a regexp that matches what you want to keep. Put `.*` around it to match the rest of the string, and replace with just the captured text.

```
str = str.replace(/.*(-\d+(?:\.\d+)?).*/, "$1");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/02SsBD/1)

Comment: when I add this `--|125a44` it's not getting `125` - is there any way to fix this?

Comment: That doesn't look like an allowable input according to your description. It has to be `-` immediately followed by a number.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... How to combine both or what this the correct syntax to replace? ..."*

Try the following *capture pattern*.

```
/\S*?(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?)\S*/g
```

- `\S*? ... \S*`, optionally preceded, and succeeded, by any non *white-space* character.
- `(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?)`, capture any number optionally succeeded by a *decimal value*, and optionally succeeded by a value in *scientific notation*.

Here is an example.

```js
var s = 
`--123 should be -123
a-123 should be -123
!-123- should be -123
+-123.44x should be -123.44
--123.33- should be -123.33`
var p = /\S*?(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?)\S*/g
s = s.replaceAll(p, '$1')

console.log(s)
```

Comment: This `[^\b]` does not mean `by any non word boundary`, that would be `\B` If you paste the pattern in regex101 and hover the `[^\b]` it says it matches a backspace character.

Answer (score -1):

you could do it like this:

```
function cleanString(str) {
  return str.replace(/^\w*|\D*$/g, '');
}
```

- `^\w*`: This removes any word characters at the start.
  |: OR
- `\D*$`: This removes any non-digit characters at the end.
- `g`: Global flag, to replace all instances.